# def vs final def in Groovy

Tags: groovy, spock

I've written simple test in `Groovy` using [Spock framework](http://spockframework.org/)

```
class SimpleSpec extends Specification {

    def "should add two numbers"() {
        given:
            final def a = 3
            final b = 4
        when:
            def c = a + b
        then:
            c == 7
    }
}
```

Variable `a` is declared using `def` and `final` keywords combination. Variable `b` is declared using only `final` keyword.

My question is: what's the difference (if any) between these two declarations? Should one approach be preffed to the other? If so, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User *daggett* ist right, `final` does not make a local variable final in Groovy. The keyword only has influence on class members. Here is a little illustration:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyTest extends Specification {
  def "Final local variables can be changed"() {
    when:
    final def a = 3
    final b = 4
    final int c = 5
    then:
    a + b + c == 12

    when:
    a = b = c = 11
    then:
    a + b + c == 33
  }

  final def d = 3
  static final e = 4
  final int f = 5

  def "Class or instance members really are final"() {
    expect:
    d + e + f == 12

    when:
    // Compile errors:
    // cannot modify final field 'f' outside of constructor.
    // cannot modify static final field 'e' outside of static initialization block.
    // cannot modify final field 'd' outside of constructor.
    d = e = f = 11
    then:
    d + e + g == 33
  }
}
```

---

When I switched one of my Spock projects to version 1.3 with Groovy 2.5 and noticed that this test no longer compiles now due to the compiler detecting the reassignment to final local variables. I.e. the inconsistency in Groovy <= 2.4 seems to be fixed.

Comment: Please see my update concerning changed behaviour in Groovy 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

final variables declared inside the methods are processed as usual variables in groovy

check the class below and the one generated by groovy (2.4.11)

ps: possible the `given:` section in spock generates code differently...
[image]

Comment: so, there is no difference?

Comment: I think your screenshot tells nothing relevant, probably you posted the wrong one. I think you wanted to show us the bytecode view or subnodes of the AST tree. Maybe you want to fix that.

Comment: I wanted to show that after parsing, conversion, and canonicalization steps the both variables declaration are the same, so the later steps will not change this declaration, and in the byte code you'll not see the diff. If i'm wrong please post your correct answer.

Comment: I never said you were wrong! I even mentioned you in my answer illustrating the same thing in a test. I just thought that you wanted to share another screenshot. The explanation for the one you did share was not very enlightening to me, only now I am able to see it. It is kinda easy to overlook that there is just `java.lang.Object a = 111` without `final` in the AST browser source view. A little more explanatory prose than "check the picture below" or a red frame around the relevant part would have been helpful.